# check if url contains string using react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a link which contains a youtube string, now I would like to check if this URL contains a string `youtube` using react hooks in react js

Here is what I have so far

```
useEffect(() => {
    let srcLink ="www.google.com/https://img.youtube.com/vi/h9-qcy3HQnM/0.jpg";
    let convertedString= srcLink.toLowerCase();

    if(convertedString.indexOf('youtube') != -1){
        alert("url has youtube");
    }else{
        alert('NOPE')
    }   
})
```

but I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

What is wrong here? or any better solution ?

Comment: I've copied your code to https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-firefly-u4qrd?file=/src/App.js and clearly it works. You will need to share more code, perhaps the entire component if possible

Comment: Your code works well, your problem is related to another issue. Share your whole code if is possible.

Comment: use `convertedString.includes('youtube')` instead of `convertedString.indexOf('youtube') != -1`  and see if it works well for you else this can be an issue created by something else

Answer (score -1):

You're probably better off using a regex here, try the below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let srcLink ="www.google.com/https://img.youtube.com/vi/h9-qcy3HQnM/0.jpg";
    let convertedString= srcLink.toLowerCase();

    if(/youtube/g.test(convertedString)){
        alert("url has youtube");
    }else{
        alert('NOPE')
    }   
})
```

Here are some good resources to learn about regex:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

https://regex101.com/

https://regexr.com/

Comment: Why is a regex better?

Comment: Your "answer" does not really answer his question, OP's problem is hitting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function`

Comment: Op asked if there was a better solution - i suggested regex as a better solution as it's cleaner and in many case, more performant

Comment: Well for a cleaner solution  `convertedString.includes('youtube')` is probably better. As of performance here is a [benchmark](https://jsben.ch/NyhKI) of the difference, they are almost similair